# File tranfer from the server

Tags: files, rsync

I want move (not copy with `scp`) my file from the server to the local repository and finally delete it on the server after transfer. I use next command from the repository, where I want have the file:

```
rsync -rvt --delete-after user@host:/path .
```

I really copy the files by this way. Anyway, the files on the server are not deleted.... It is necessary to do: `rm -r filename`

Can somebody improve my linux statement and show me, how I can transfer and remove file from the original place in one move.

PS

According to the answer of @user1008764 I want add here additional useful link to the another discussion (how to delete not only the file, but also the directory):
https://superuser.com/questions/676671/rsync-does-not-delete-source-directories

Comment: try --remove-source-files instead of --delete-after.
have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/363922/how-to-move-files-with-scp

Comment: @user1008764 please put that as an answer so this could be a solved question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `--remove-source-files` instead of `--delete-after`.
have a look at serverfault.com/questions/363922/how-to-move-files-with-scp